# How can I format (new lines) in bodyText of ui.bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, showmodaldialog, ui.bootstrap

I have in my AngularJS-script a ui.bootstrap confirmdlg:

```
var modalDlgOptions = {
  closeButtonText: "No",
  actionButtonText: "Yes",
  headerText: "my header text",
  bodyText: "my body text" 
};
confirmDlg.showModal({}, modalDlgOptions).then(function (result) {
  // todo something         
});
```

This works fine. But now I want to format the bodyText. I need new lines like this:

```
first line in my body text
second line in my body text
...
last line in my body text
```

When I use

```
bodyText: "first line in my body text<br>second line in my body text<br>...<br>last line in my body text";
```

or

```
bodyText: "first line in my body text&lt;br&gt;second line in my body text&lt;br&gt;...&lt;br&gt;last line in my body text";
```

I get

```
first line in my body text&lt;br&gt;second line in my body text&lt;br&gt;...&lt;br&gt;last line in my body text
```

in output of my dialog, but **not new lines**.

Is it possible to format the bodyText of the confirmDlg and how?

Thank you for your hints, Thomas

Comment: Have you tried `<br />` or wrap the line inside of `<p></p>`

Comment: need to use `ng-bind-html` and include `ngSanitize` script in app...see docs

Comment: A better solution, more maintainable, is to use a html partial and just place your HTML in there - it will make the code a lot more readable.  See 'templateUrl' in the Modal control here - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
var modalDlgOptions = {
  closeButtonText: "No",
  actionButtonText: "Yes",
  headerText: "my header text",
  bodyText: "" 
};

confirmDlg.showModal({}, modalDlgOptions).then(function (result) {
  // todo something         
}); 

setTimeout(function() { 
  var modalBody = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body");
  modalBody[0].innerHTML = "first line in my body text<br />second line in my body text<br /> ... <br />last line in my body text";
}, 100);
```

Thanks for the comments, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

**Improving** the previous solution:

```
var waitForElementByClassName  = function(element, timeout, callBack) {
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        if (document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0]){
          callBack(document.getElementsByClassName(element)[0]);
        } else {
            waitForElementByClassName(element, timeout, callBack);
        }
      }, timeout);
};

waitForElementByClassName("modal-body", 50, function(element) {
        element.innerHTML = "first line in my body text<br />second line in my body text<br /> ... <br />last line in my body text";
        });
```